# shell alias executes in home directory

Tags: bash, sed, find, sh, pwd

I have following line in my `.zshrc` file:

```
alias clean="sed -i 's/\r//g; s/    /\t/g' $(find . -maxdepth 1 -type f)"
```

but when I try to execute it in `/path/to/some/directory` the output is:

```
sed ./.Xauthority
./.lesshst: No such file or directory
```

`.Xauthority` and `.lesshst` are both in my home directory.

Substitutiong `.` with `$(pwd)` dos not help.

Comment: Which shell do you use?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When defining the alias you've used double quotes to encompass the entire (alias) definition.  This has the effect of actually running the `find` command at the time the alias is defined.

So when the alias is created it will pick up a list of files from the directory in which the alias is being defined (eg, in your home directory when sourcing `.zshrc`).

You can see this happening in the following example:

```
$ cd /tmp

$ pwd
/tmp

$ ls -l
total 36036
drwxrwxrwt+ 1 myid None                  0 Oct 10 11:31 ./
drwxr-xr-x+ 1 myid None                  0 Jul 12 17:28 ../
-rw-r--r--  1 myid Administrators        0 Oct 10 11:31 a
-rw-r--r--  1 myid Administrators        0 Oct 10 11:31 b
-rw-r--r--  1 myid Administrators        0 Oct 10 11:31 c
-rw-r--r--  1 myid Administrators        0 Oct 10 11:31 d
-rw-r--r--  1 myid Administrators 36864002 Jun  6 17:29 giga.txt
drwx------+ 1 myid Administrators        0 Mar  8  2020 runtime-xward/

$ alias clean="sed -i 's/\r//g; s/    /\t/g' $(find . -maxdepth 1 -type f)"
$ alias clean
alias clean='sed -i '\''s/\r//g; s/    /\t/g'\'' ./a
./b
./c
./d
./giga.txt'
```

Notice how the `find` was evaluated at alias definition time and pulled in all of the files in my `/tmp` directory.

To address this issue you want to make sure the `find` is **not** evaluated at the time the alias is created.

There are a few ways to do this, one idea being to wrap the `find` portion of the definition in single quotes, another idea would be keep the current double quotes and just escape the `$`, eg:

```
$ alias clean="sed -i 's/\r//g; s/    /\t/g' "'$(find . -maxdepth 1 -type f)'
$ alias clean
alias clean='sed -i '\''s/\r//g; s/    /\t/g'\'' $(find . -maxdepth 1 -type f)'

$ alias alias clean="sed -i 's/\r//g; s/    /\t/g' \$(find . -maxdepth 1 -type f)"
$ alias clean
alias clean='sed -i '\''s/\r//g; s/    /\t/g'\'' $(find . -maxdepth 1 -type f)'
```

Notice in both cases the alias contains the actual `find` command instead of the results of evaluating it in the current directory.